# Room with Flow returns null when empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I've just started looking at Room, Coroutines, and Flow, and have come across something odd: what I'm expecting to be an empty flow actually has one null item in it.

My setup is as follows, with generic `T` for my actual entities.

```
interface TDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date=:date")
    fun getT(date: String): Flow<T>
}
```

```
@Singleton
class TRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: TApiService,
    private val Tdao: TDao
) {

    suspend fun getTFor(date: String): Flow<T> =
        Tdao
            .getT(date)
            .map {
                if (it == null) {
                    returnTFromDatabase()
                } else {
                    it
                }
            }
```

Now, when the database doesn't have any `T` in it for `date`, I'm expecting it to return an empty flow, with no items in it. Instead, it has one `null` element, which should never happen, because `T` isn't nullable.

I wrote this test for it:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TDatabaseTest {

    private lateinit var db: TDatabase
    private lateinit var underTest: TDao

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, TDatabase::class.java).build()
        underTest = db.TDao()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        db.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun givenEmptyDatabase_thenHasNoItems() {
        runBlocking {
            val list = underTest.getT("1999").take(1).toList()
            assertEquals(1, list.size)
        }
    }
}
```

...and it passes, cause, again, there's one `null` item returned.

What am I missing? What's wrong here, because I can't quite figure it out. Why am I getting a single null element in a flow with non nullable elements?

Comment: Room doesn't play nice with generic last time I've checked. Also, I recommend you having a read on Kotlin Generics. As the T doesn't have an upper bound the default upper bound is `Any?` ([link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html?_ga=2.229882581.851106091.1583443697-739690806.1554414496#generic-constraints))

Comment: It's not generic in my code, I've just replaced mentions of my actual entities with a mention of T. It's an actual entity in my code.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous A given `T` may be non-nullable, therefore it is never ok to pass a `null` as a `T < Any?`. You just have to remember that `T < T?`.

Answer (score 25):

How Room handles nullability depends on how you define the return type of the query function. The Docs say:

> - When the return type is `Flow<T>`, querying an empty table throws a **null pointer exception**.
> - When the return type is `Flow<T?>`, querying an empty table emits a `null` value.
> - When the return type is `Flow<List<T>>`, querying an empty table emits an **empty list**.

The above snippet discusses empty tables, but I assume the same behaviour is applicable to any query that returns no rows.

Source: [Room Docs on Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query)

Comment: The docs say it throws a null pointer exception, but in practice I received a null value in my flow as well.

Comment: There discrepancy has been reported: [Room Coroutine and Flow @Query do not handle null as expected](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213175894). Looks to still be open, as of this writing. Solutions given is to switch to KSP or declare queries to return `Flow<T?>` and filter if desired (as Pierluigi suggests in his answer).

Answer (score 23):

Room is a db written in Java and that's why it ignores Kotlin optional. I suggest to declare always query return type or, in your case, `Flow<T?>` type, optional. If you don't want a null type in the flow you can use `filterNotNull()` function like this:

```
Tdao.getT(date).filterNotNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve proper nullability with `Flow<T>` that worked for me:

- Use Room 2.6.0 or above
- Use KSP instead of KAPT
- In your app's `build.gradle`:

```
ksp {
    // Configure Room to generate Kotlin source code
    // This achieves proper nullability in Flow<T>
    arg("room.generateKotlin", "true")
}
```

There is also [Room Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#gradle-plugin) which can be used to configure this KSP option, but for me it didn't work (there seems to be some repository issue and plugin cannot be found).